# Build error in cordova if the project name starts with number

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a project whose name should be 12xxxxx. The project is created successfully, platform is added properly. But when I try to build it its throwing me an error.

```
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args
```

This error is common for all the projects if the project name starts with a number, But this works fine, if the project name starts with a letter.

Comment: maybe you are choosing appid starting with numbers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Appid can not start with a number. Go to your config.xml and change the app id. This will work.